Strange behaviour with CD4011 Latch circuit
I'm hoping someone can help me understand an issue I've had with a NAND based latch / bypass circuit. The output is connected to a 2N3904 which drives a relay, and this is the bypass circuit for a guitar pedal.

The circuit actually works fine, it's a pretty well established building block for guitar pedal designers. However, while debugging an unrelated issue today, I was toggling the circuit on and off manually, and noticed something strange.
At first I was using some metal clippers with insulated handles, and just tapping the connector pins where the footswitch normally connects, to toggle it on and off. This was fine.
But I later did this again, with a non-insulated metal screwdriver. I tapped it a few times, and then all of a sudden, the latch ceased to function, and the 4011 chip got extremely hot and was clearly drawing a lot of current. the only way to recover was to unplug the power supply.
I replicated this behaviour multiple times, and it consistently "froze" after I tapped it 4-5 times with the uninsulated screwdriver, but I could toggle it multiple times with an insulated instrument, or if I just connected the footswitch (the terminals on that are also insulated).
I couldn't tell if the circuit was stuck self-oscillating, or if both the high and low CMOS transistors inside the IC were somehow in a stable "on" state, causing an internal short.
Any theory as to why this might happen would be greatly appreciated. I'd also like to develop some kind of safety to keep the chip from self-destructing, in case of a random event where this might occur when the device is in a customers hands. I'm thinking of adding small resistors to the NAND outputs (470 ohm). Thoughts?

This is called "latch-up" and is a long-known issue (problem) with many CMOS integrated circuits.
Essentially the entire chip has a parasitic SCR across the supply lines and you should avoid triggering it or the power drawn from the supply can destroy the chip. It's generally an indirect form of damage- the chip has some ESD protection to keep it from being damaged during handling, but if it gets triggered the supply current continues to flow until the power is cycled or the chip destroys itself. It can be triggered by input voltages that both exceed the supply rails and allow more than a few mA to flow. Even a very brief such voltage, as might come from discharging your body capacitance through the screwdriver.
In general, it's best to avoid connecting CMOS IC pins directly to anything that a user can come into contact with. Especially inputs, but outputs as well.
You could add a series resistor (eg. 1kΩ) to pin 4 and another series resistor (eg. 10kΩ) to pins 1 & 2. Also a 1uF bypass capacitor across the supply lines and a dual diode from the switch to Vdd and GND.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

ESD event causing a latch-up condition.
CMOS chips are very sensitive and these old 4000 series chips may damage from ESD.
Also the circuit is weird, the switch will short circuit the output of lower gate to capacitor, and shorting outouts is something a good properly operating circuit should never not do.
Basically, it might mostly work, but the chip should be used properly. It does not matter if it is a pretty established circuit, that's still a case of copying around a poor circuit just because everyone else uses it. That unfortunately happens a lot.

Thank you, this is really helpful


But I later did this again, with a non-insulated metal screwdriver. I
tapped it a few times, and then all of a sudden, the latch ceased to
function, and the 4011 chip got extremely hot and was clearly drawing
a lot of current. the only way to recover was to unplug the power
supply.

A screwdriver could develop quite an ESD charge and blow out the gates, which is probably most likely happening. Put a 10V TVS diode after the switch to ground to protect against ESD events.
